# How do I search for a specific opponent/player on phone?

Tags: star-wars-commander

My brother just got Star Wars: Commander and I want to raid him for a bit of banter but how do I search his username? If it's not possible, is there a way I can search for the squad that he is in and start a squad war? We both play on our phones, I play on a Windows phone and he plays on an iPhone, will the type of phone make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

ANSWER: The Type of Game Device Matters.

1. Star Wars Commander Windows Version is being shut down / closed effective June 30, 2017.
2. Star Wars Commander Players using Windows Game Devices can not raid / attack a  Star Wars Commander Player using iOS/Android Game Device since they are/were on two separate Game Servers.
3. Star Wars Commander Players whom are both using iOS/Android Game Devices, as long as they are in different Factions, can raid / attack another - provided they are randomly matched via PvP Matchmaking Process. This is not guaranteed and very difficult to accomplish since both Players need to be on same Planet and both Players need to be close to the same HQ Level / Base Strength.
4. While it is possible to search in-game for a Squad Name (since Squad Names are Unique) you can not search for In-Game Player Name (since they are NOT Unique). If you searched for - say "Darth Vader" - you would find thousands of them.
5. Finding another Players Squad does NOT guarantee you will be matched to that Squad in a Squad War.